# Can I save my message, inbox and also my own location, at the time of message has come?

Tags: android

My problem is to store the messages default location (inbox, sent items) and also saves in my own location at the time of message is coming and sending the message. I will create any background service to identify the when will message is coming. Please give me an idea………………………

Comment: Could you clarify a little more what you are trying to accomplish and what you have tried already?

Comment: Mr Charles my application is store the inbox messages when the application is run.My problem is android phone Receives a message at that time my application is run.How to identify the when will come message.